# Swift 4 - Alamofire post request with httpbody

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have this Alamofire post request like so:

```swift
var jsonArrayOfDictionaries = [[AnyHashable: Any]]()

let user = appDelegate.username
let password = appDelegate.password

let url = webservice + "PostTasks"
let credential = URLCredential(user: user!, password: password!, persistence: .forSession)
let headers = ["Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", "Content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"]
let jsonData: Data? = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonArrayOfDictionaries, options: .prettyPrinted)

print(jsonData!)

//request.httpBody = jsonData

Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, headers: headers).authenticate(usingCredential: credential).responseJSON {
        (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            if let value = response.result.value {

                print(value)

                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({

                    completion(true)

                })


            }else{

                print("There is error in the server response")

                completion(false)

            }

        case .failure (let error):

            print("The NTLM request error is: ", error.localizedDescription)

            completion(false)

        }

    }
```

My question is how do I add the jsonData variable to the httpbody of this request? I have looked into this issue and all the solutions appear to be old. Please help!

This is how jsonArrayOfDictionaries is getting populated:

```
var jsonArrayOfDictionaries = [[AnyHashable: Any]]()

        for i in 0..<cellHolder.count {

            var jsonDict = [AnyHashable: Any]()

            jsonDict["scheduleTaskID"] = cellHolder[i].scheduleTaskID

            jsonDict["task"] = cellHolder[i].task

            jsonDict["scheduledDate"] = cellHolder[i].scheduledDate

            jsonDict["actualDate"] = cellHolder[i].actualDate

            jsonDict["finishedDate"] = cellHolder[i].finishedDate

            jsonDict["selected"] = (cellHolder[i].selected) ? 1 : 0

            jsonDict["completedBy"] = appDelegate.username

            jsonDict["sortOrder"] = cellHolder[i].sortOrder

            jsonArrayOfDictionaries.append(jsonDict)

            jsonDict = [AnyHashable: Any]()

        }
```

Its in a loop and gets appended.

Comment: Unrelated but never `prettyPrint` anything which is going to be sent to a server. The server doesn't care.

Comment: Have you tried to put in the JsonData object in as part of the parameters argument? Like this:

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters:jsonData, headers: headers).authenticate(usingCredential: credential).responseJSON {
                    (response) in

Comment: @LoupG I get this error: Cannot convert value of type 'Data?' to expected argument type 'Parameters?' (aka 'Optional<Dictionary<String, Any>>')

Comment: @user979331yes thats expected. The parameters object should be of type dictionary ([String: Any]) not of type Data. Why dont you try using jsonArrayOfDictionaries as it is without converting to Data?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Change**

```
let jsonData: Data? = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonArrayOfDictionaries, options: .prettyPrinted)
```

**to**

`let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonArrayOfDictionaries, options: []) as? [String : Any]`

**2. Add jsonData to your request**

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, headers: headers, parameters: jsonData).authenticate(usingCredential: credential).responseJSON {
```

Comment: I get this warning for jsonData: Cast from 'Data' to unrelated type '[String : Any]' always fails

Comment: Did you deleted the `: Data?` as well?

Comment: Yes I did, I still get the error: Cast from 'Data' to unrelated type '[String : Any]' always fails

Comment: Check now please, with `JSONSerialization.jsonObject`

Comment: New error: Cannot invoke 'jsonObject' with an argument list of type '(with: [[AnyHashable : Any]], options: [Any])'

Comment: @user979331 this might be a dirty way to send your data to the server but it should work: let bigDict = ["data": jsonData] then use bigDict as the parameter in the request. On the server side, you must parse accordingly too. Goodluck

Comment: It does not work, I get this error: Cannot invoke 'jsonObject' with an argument list of type '(with: [[AnyHashable : Any]], options: [Any])'

Comment: @user979331 did you see my edit to create a bigDict dictionary constant of type [string:any]. See the last comment i wrote

Comment: @LoupG can you put an example in an answer? Please and thank you.

Comment: @user979331 Ok. But I think what it boils down to is transforming your data to be posted into a dictionary of type [String: Any]. If you can do that successfully, you should be able to post it.